# Galaxy S3 Tmobile - Can't boot into Clockword Recover?

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery, recovery-mode

I hold down power up + home + power and it brings me to a screen that says Android System Recovery - I can't get the Clockwork Recovery. 
What could be the problem?

Comment: Do you have a ROM or kernel that has CWM installed?

Comment: I have d/l and installed clockworksmod recovery. nothing beyond that.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to flash an other package after you install CWM. The Galaxy SIII has checks in its start up scripts that if the recovery has been modified it will replace it with the stock recovery.

You can try [this Root Package](http://www.epiccm.org/2012/06/team-epics-root-from-recovery.html) and flash it after you flash CWM. Besides installing SU and superuser, this removes the scripts that does the Recovery Check.

The actual scripts that are responsible are :

1. /system/etc/install-recovery.sh
2. /system/etc/recovery-from-boot.p

The package, that I linked, will install root, busybox, and it renames these files so they don't execute.

When the device boots, these scripts run and check the recovery, if you modify it, it replaces it with stock. The only way around it is to stop these scripts from running.

Comment: Anyone out there have any suggestions??

Comment: what do you mean by suggestions?

Comment: Ryan thanks for the reply. (Ignore the online line msg I wrote it before seeing our reply and tried to erased it but I guess I didn't.)
I went to link you posted. I took the TeamEpic-Root-from-Recovery-v*.zip copied it to the phone. 
But the instructions on the site is:

-Copy TeamEpic-Root-from-Recovery-v*.zip in your phone's internal storage.
-Boot into Recovery.
-Flash TeamEpic-Root-from-Recovery-v*.zip.

but I only get into Android System Recovery and there is no option there to Flash anything.

Here is where I'm stuck.

Comment: Ryan, sorry the format is all messed up, I am new to this site and don't know how to work it better.

Comment: once you flash CWM with odin, you need to boot directly in to recovery, without rebooting the phone first.

Comment: so I missed that step? then do I just do over the odin step? will that hurt anything?

Comment: yes, redo the process from the beginning. no, it will not hurt anything.